# Files flattened and merged with PDFBox are sharing common COSStream

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

the following code demonstrates a very strange bug. Once the "source" file is closed the "destination" file can not be saved and closed, it will throw "java.io.IOException: COSStream has been closed and cannot be read. Perhaps its enclosing PDDocument has been closed?"

If we comment out saving the source file, then the destination will save and close properly. This seems to clearly indicate that the source file contained a COSStream object that also existed in the destination file. The source file COSStream seems to get closed when we close the source file and then the destination can't be saved.

If we comment out flattening the source files AcroForm then the destination will save and close properly.

This simplistic example is trying to merge one copy of the form with itself, the bug will reproduce if you substitute certain other PDF files (all government forms that used to be XFA documents). Most PDFs will work in this scenario. We down converted the XFA documents to normal PDF to eliminate that as a variable and the bug still persisted.

Issue exists in PDFBox version 2.0.8 and older

```
    @Test
    public void testMergeGovernmentForms() throws Exception {
    File file = new File("GeneralForbearance.pdf");
    PDDocument destination = PDDocument.load(file);

    PDDocument source = PDDocument.load(file);
    source.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().flatten(); //comment out just this line and the destination.save will pass

    PDFMergerUtility appender = new PDFMergerUtility();

    appender.appendDocument(destination, source);

    source.close(); //comment out just this line and the destination.save will pass

    destination.save(File.createTempFile("PrintMergeIssue", ".pdf"));
    destination.close();

}
```

Download the GeneralForbearance.pdf from [HERE](https://studentloans.gov/myDirectLoan/downloadForm.action?searchType=library&shortName=general&localeCode=en-us)

Additionally, if you "pre-flatten" the government form and save, you get the same behavior with even simpler code.

```
    @Test
public void testMerge() throws Exception {
    PDFMergerUtility pdfMergerUtility = new PDFMergerUtility();
    PDDocument src = PDDocument.load(new File("C:/temp/GovFormPreFlattened.pdf"));
    PDDocument dest = PDDocument.load(new File("C:/temp/GovFormPreFlattened.pdf"));
    pdfMergerUtility.appendDocument(dest, src);
    src.close(); //if we don't close the src then we don't have an error
    dest.save(File.createTempFile("MergeIssue",".PDF"));
    dest.close();
}
```

The pre-flattened government form can be found [HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18JbNK1gBivSARvv9kgd5FE8xnD_9-_15/view?usp=drivesdk)

Comment: *"Additionally, if you "pre-flatten" the government form and save, you get the same behavior with even simpler code."* - That is really interesting. In the original version I thought something like the observed behavior was to be expected or at least possible, but that the same happens with the simpler code is really interesting.

Comment: This happens to save space... although I thought that with merging it doesn't happen, because of deep cloning.

Comment: We are merging thousands of individual documents into bulk PDF files to send to the mail room. Are we supposed to keep all the source documents open while we populate the output? Is it intended behavior that closing a source PDF would close a COSStream in the output file? It seems to me that an object was not cloned properly when it was merged from source to destination. I appreciate your help.

Comment: As @Tilman indicated in his comment, he thought that should not be necessary at least in pure merging use cases, i.e. in your simpler code.

Comment: My current suspicion is that it is related to not removing the fields from the structure tree when flattening. That one is optional (describes the logical structure of the document) and you can delete it with `document.getDocumentCatalog().setStructureTreeRoot(null);`

Comment: actually we went to great effort to get the StructTreeRoot into our documents, this is a critical component to 508 compliant tagging. We are trying to get PDFBox to merge a tagged and untagged document without losing tags. Currently PDFBox 2.0.8 will strip all tags when merging a tagged and untagged document.

Comment: By the way, our solution to get PDFBox to merge tagged and untagged documents without losing tags was to first add tags to the untagged document. We use the Overlay class to overlay the untagged document onto a tagged resource PDF that just has a tag that says "this part of the  document is not tagged". If you do it the other way around, overlay the tagged resource file onto the untagged document then it comes out untagged.

Answer (score 0):

There were several issues in the PDFMergerUtility merging tagged documents which I fixed, patched, and submitted back to Apache as issue [PDFBOX-3999](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3999), download the patch from there if you need it. This patch applies to version 2.0.8

Comment: Thanks, I (or another committer) will review this soon. I'll also create two more issues relared to this, one being the failure to remove/alter the field from the structure. This is a snake pit :-(

Comment: Please add a text that it will be fixed in 2.0.10. Although your patch wasn't used, you still get a "thank you" from me, because it triggered me to create a test and to find a solution, although only many months later when I had a fresh look at this.

Comment: This and many other structure tree issues ( https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-4419?jql=labels%20%3D%20StructureTree )  have been fixed now. Please try with a snapshot or build from source.